# select from a table a value that is unique and the min

Tags: mysql

I want to select from a table a value that is unique and the min

For example, I have a table (User, name, price); I want to return the user who paid the min price and the price is repeated only once.

The price is not known. It's given by the user because it's an auction.

For example, if I have...

```
user   name    price
1      jo      30
2      ko      50
3      lo      30
4      po      55
```

...then the winner is user 2 because his price is not repeated and is the minimum. 30 is smallest but it's repeated

How can I return user 2?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach to do this.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM MyTable t0
WHERE t0.id IN
  (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM
    MyTable
  GROUP BY value
  HAVING count(*) = 1
  )
ORDER BY value
LIMIT 1
```

where `MyTable` is

```
| id | name | value |
|----|------|-------|
|  1 |   jo |    30 |
|  2 |   ko |    50 |
|  3 |   lo |    30 |
|  4 |   po |    55 |
```

And the output is

```
| id | name | value |
|----|------|-------|
|  2 |   ko |    50 |
```

The subquery inside will provide the ids which have no duplicates.  In this case it would be `2,4`.

Comment: And the t0? what does it referes to?

Comment: I used it but it returned a duplicate value

Comment: The `t0` is an alias and on the `FROM` clause there is an implied `AS` (optional). Same as `FROM MyTable as t0` - just a way to shortcut typing long names. FYI - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)

Comment: What returned value do you see?

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
select * from category_list where item_price not in(select item_price from category_list where id not in(select id from category_list group by item_price)) order by item_price limit 1
```

replace column field name with your field name